# has_many, through relationship not populating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to allow User modals to add and remove individual settings for other Users, but I cannot get the `has_many ... through` relationship to work correctly: I am able to create new Setting modals, but I cannot retrieve or delete them.

Here is my User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :settings, class_name:  "Setting",
                              foreign_key: "user_id",
                              dependent:   :destroy

  has_many :user_settings, through: :settings, source: :user

  def create_settings(user)
    settings.create(following_id: user.id)
  end

  def delete_settings(user)
    settings.find_by(following_id: user.id).destroy
  end

  def has_settings?(user)
    user_settings.include?(user)
  end
...
```

Here is my Setting.rb:

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, class_name: "User"
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :following_id, presence: true
end
```

I call the creation/deletion methods with these `users_controller` functions:

```
def add_settings
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  if !@user.has_settings?(user)
    @user.create_settings(user)
    @user.save
  end
end

def remove_settings
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  if @user.has_settings?(user)
    @user.delete_settings(user)
    @user.save
  end
end
```

If I call `add_settings` and then `remove_settings` I get a success response both times, but if I call `add_settings` again, I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_settings_on_user_id_and_following_id"
```

So it seems `has_settings` in User.rb is always returning false and the user setting is never removed when the controller function `remove_settings` is called.

Why isn't the `user_settings` relationship being populated? How can I get `has_settings` to return the correct value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user_settings.include?(user)` will always return false, since `user_settings` is a collection of `user_setting` objects, not `user` objects. Furthermore, calling `include?` here might not be efficient as it requires loading multiple `user_settings` objects into memory to compare each one.

Depending on how `user_settings`, and `settings` are defined you should be able to use the following query to check if there are any `user_settings` which belong to this user (`self`). Try the following query:

```
def has_settings?(user)
  settings.exists?(following_id: user.id)
end
```